# How do I return an application from the notification area to the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, notifications, roaming-profiles

One of our users has the problem that whenever she minimizes a specific application, it gets minimized to the notification area instead of to the taskbar. The application does not appear in the notification area when it is non-minimized, it instead does appear on the taskbar. That is, unless she has focused on another application, in that case it does neither appear in the taskbar, nor in the notification area.

This problem is only present for this user, regardless of which computer on our network she uses, and does not appear for other people using those computers.

Apart from recreating her profile (which will almost certainly fix the problem) is there another way to get rid of this behaviour?

Comment: More information is required to answer this problem. What is the application in question that does this? For all you know it is an application setting she activated. Alternatively it could be a program that does this, but guesswork never is a good thing.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of any such options, but checked again and it turned out there is an option in the program, your comment made me solve it. The program in question is a custom application for keeping track of legal files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow you to mark this as solved, here is a solution version of my comment:

Check if the program itself has an option to minimize to the system tray. She likely has activated that.